# 3 way nested ANOVA in R / SPSS?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, spss, nested-data

It is not clear to me how to carry the following ANOVA analysis out in R or SPSS (or ideally both).

I have an experiment in which I am measuring the response time (dependent variable) by 20 subjects for 6 cognitive tasks: 3 visual and 3 auditory. A subject does each task only once. This gives the following factors:

- Factor 1: Modality (visual, auditory)
- Factor 2: Task (color, shape, depth, frequency, intensity, duration)
- Factor 3: Subject (s1, s2, ... , s20)

So each subject does all 6 tasks once, with the factor Task nested in Modality: {color, shape, depth} are visual tasks and {frequency, intensity, duration} are auditory tasks.

How would I get such a nested ANOVA entered in SPSS and/or R, taking into account subject variance (so that would make subjects a random factor)?

For R I got so far (but not sure if correct):

```
aov(RT ~ Modality/Task + Error(Subject), data=d)
```

Is this correct? And how could the analysis as described above be entered in SPSS?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not use an ANOVA framework, but instead a linear mixed model/multilevel modeling approach. I am quite fond of [the `lme4` package.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf) I find [this page](http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer) to be a good introduction to the package (even though the page is focused on longitudinal models, the model specifications and multilevel structure of the data are the same). That page will get to the various ways of modeling data, hypothesis tests (e.g., t-tests or likelihood ratio tests?), etc.

On to your data. First, you cannot see how task interacts with modality, because they are orthogonal: color, shape, and depth are all visual; frequency, intensity, and duration are all auditory tasks. There is no crossing: You can't see if reaction time of color depends on if it is an auditory or visual task (i.e., an interaction) because ALL color tasks are visual.

Have you tried conducting a factor analysis on these data? You may be able to reduce dimensionality here by just including visual or auditory. It depends on your research question, I suppose. But I would first try to see if two factors can more parsimoniously describe your data than six separate measures. However, this would involve multilevel factor analysis—something I do not have experience with.

But getting back to the point...

The data you have are such that observations are nested within people. The simplest model would just compare visual vs. auditory:

```
lmer(RT ~ Modality + (1 + Modality | Subject), data = d)
```

What does this code mean? `lmer` is the function in the `lme4` package for fitting linear mixed effects models. I'm specifying that reaction time (`RT`) is predicted by a fixed effect of `Modality`. Then I specify all of the random effects in parentheses next. The `1` means I am specifying a random intercept, which means that I am allowing every person to have a different intercept (in this case, the mean reaction time in your reference condition). The `Modality` after it means that we are specifying a random slope, which in this case means that we are allowing the effect of `Modality` to differ across people—we are letting the mean of the *other* (non-reference) condition to vary by person. Lastly, we have a pipe (`|`) and then `Subject`, which means we are nesting observations within person.

You could also look at each task separately, specifying:

```
lmer(RT ~ Task + (1 + Task | Subject), data = d)
```

As long as you have `Task` specified as a factor (you can check this by entering `class(d$Task)`, then the package will dummy-code it for you, and you can do pairwise comparisons using the [`multcomp` package and the `glht` function.](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-test-contrasts-in-r/)

It sounds like you might be tempted to model the task nested within the modality of the task. Some might disagree, but I think this is a **bad** idea. We generally assume that things you nested within are sampled from a population (like people, places, classrooms, schools, plots of land, etc.). You are not sampling tasks from a population of modalities. There are two modalities: auditory and visual.

I would try running either of the two models, depending on what suits your research question best.

Comment: Mark, thanks. This is very helpful I have not tried conducting a factor analysis yet. Conceptually, nesting observations within subject instead of nesting task within the modality makes sense. My research question is aimed at testing wether there is a general Modality effect, which is addressed by the simplest model you suggested. (and if there is, I was thinking to test whether specific tasks drive this).